# Override create for a debugging purpose (doesn't work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To debug the methods create and create! for a model I did this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create
    puts "----MyModel.rb create"
    super.create
  end

  def create!
    puts "----MyModel.rb create!"
    super.create!
  end

end
```

But I don't see these debug messages in the terminal when I run `rake db:seed` Of course, the instances of `MyModel` are created.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. these methods should be class methods
2. It accepts some [params](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/create)

This works for me

```
def self.create(attributes = nil, &block)
    p "======================="
    p 'aaaaaaaaaaa'
    p "======================="
    super
  end
```

in console

```
> User.create(email: 'aaa')
"======================="
"aaaaaaaaaaa"
"======================="
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'aaa' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<User id: nil, email: "aaa",...
```